# Is there any test framework or any other way to test async methods in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I have a bunch of async functions in java that I want to test. I would like to have a functionality where the main thread waits until all the tests are done. The method signature of these functions looks like as follows

```
public class Callback {
    public void onSucess(Result result) {
        return result.getLastName(); 
    }
}

public class client{

    public static void getLastNameAsync(String firstname, Callback cb);

    public static void getLastNameAsync(String middlename, Callback cb);
    ...................................
    ...................................
    ...................................
    Imagine there are more functions like this 
}
```

I want to be be able to test the client class as follows

```
    public void TestClient(){
        Client client = new Client();
        client.getLastNameAsync("Brandon", new callback());
        client.getLastNameAsync("kyle", new callback());
        ....................
        ....................
        ....................

        Imagine I have to test more functions like this
    }
```

countDownLatch seems to be a solution however I need to know the number of method calls I am invoking and even if I do that seems to be a hacky solution because I need to instantiate as below

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(#number of methods calls in my TestClient);
The trick again here is knowing #number of methods calls in my TestClient
```

open to any kind of advice or solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static methods are not your friend.  I would use instance classes, and then use an Executor as the means to control whether the execution is synchronous or asynchronous.

For your production code, inject a ThreadPoolExecutor in order for your logic to defer to another thread (or threads).  But, in your test case, use a DirectExecutor to execute the logic in the same thread.  See the javadoc for java.util.concurrent.Executor

This way, your test code will be far simpler.  I'm sure you want to test the logic being called.  If you need to test the multi-threadedness of it, you can then start to approach that as well.  But if you don't have to, then keeping things simple will help in the test.  And static methods don't help with that.

Comment: Hi the static method is just an example. It can very well be instance methods only infact I just edited my sample code above. The main thing here is I want one thread to execute all my async methods and that thread should wait until all the callbacks finish executing! That I am not sure how to do it using ThreadpoolExecutor given my async methods return type is void but not Future.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the comment.  The sole method of an Executor is void execute(Runnable runnable).  So an Executor does not mandate the use of a Future.  Given that there is no code, I'll have to presume that your code which accepts the Callable starts its own thread.  Instead of doing that, use an Executor which executes a Runnable (which will contain the methods you want to test).  The key part is, during the test, use an Executor implementation that simply calls the Runnable.run method in the same thread.  Don't bother with multiple threads if you don't need to test that part.

Comment: I've created some samples of what I am suggesting.  It can be found at https://gist.github.com/hildo/ccb2c823e6d914ce96bc  This uses JUnit, by the way

Comment: First of all, Thank you a ton for your effort!! The Thread that calls obj.getLastName("nameToFind", callback); will be returned immediately(before the callback you passed even gets invoked) since getLastName is an Async function. (If it does here or not I am not sure but that is how the async methods should work(non blocking)). so @L17 in ClassToTestTest I am not sure 100% if it is guaranteed that the callback will have have a value to check ?

Comment: The point I am trying to make is the getLastName method is only executing its logic on a different thread when it uses the default executor.  When the test method injects a new Executor (an instance of the DirectExecutor), the DirectExecutor.execute method calls the run method of the provided Runnable.  So, during the test, the Runnable will be executed by the same thread calling the method.  In the test, via the DirectExecutor, the Callback will be used as part of the run() method.  So it should be populated by the time the getLastName method completed in the test.